# Console in java not showing data from an sql table

Tags: java, sql

**Expectation** : This code is supposed to show the data of the table book in the console, but for some reason it doesn't.

**Issue** : It does show driver name and everything related to the driver, but not the title and ISBN of the book.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Act1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection connection=null;

        try {
            String dbUrl="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=libreria;user=user1;password=pass";
            connection=DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl);
            if (connection != null) {
                DatabaseMetaData dn= (DatabaseMetaData) connection.getMetaData();
                System.out.println("Driver name: "+ dn.getDriverName());
                System.out.println("Drive Version: "+ dn.getDriverVersion());
                System.out.println("Product name: "+ dn.getDatabaseProductName());
                System.out.println("Product Version: "+ dn.getDatabaseProductName());
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    
        try {
            PreparedStatement pst= null;
            try {
                pst= connection.prepareStatement("Select* from book");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ResultSet rs = null;
            try {
                rs= pst.executeQuery();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            try {
                while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("Isbn: "+ rs.getInt("isbn")+ " Title: "+rs.getString("title"));
                    
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } finally {
            
        }       
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the table is not just empty ... ?

Comment: `} catch (SQLException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }` -- This section allows the code to continue instead of stopping and returning. If there's an exception you shouldn't continue at all.

Comment: `Select*` --> `Select *` -- Add a space.